# canvas drawImage onload function not working

Tags: javascript, svg

In this code i have get base64 value from svg element. Because of i want png/jpg value to create image from canvas but its not working image onload function.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var svgData = document.getElementById("svgdiv").innerHTML;
    var url = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgData);
    getBase64FromImageUrl(url);
    });
    function getBase64FromImageUrl(URL) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = URL;
    console.log(img);

    img.onload = function() {// here code not working
        console.log("FDF");
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));

    };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code `img.src = URL;` and `console.log(img)` should _follow_ the code that assigns a handler to the onload event. I.e, you should set the behaviour for the onload event, _then_ you should set the source of the img element and attempt to load it. The `console.log` call could very well be taking longer than the loading of the image, in which case, the image has already loaded before you assign a handler for the onload event.

Comment: I remove console.log(img). but still not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to assign the `.src` attribute of the `img` ***after*** you've assigned the onload handler. Removing the `console.log` call still doesn't do this. Granted, it does reduce the time between assigning the `src` and assigning the onload handler, but this is not the way to do it.

Here's your code with the required extra stuff to make it a fully functional example. Note the order of the assignments and the `console.log` call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}

function toggleClass(elem, className){elem.classList.toggle(className);}
function toggleClassById(targetElemId, className){byId(targetElemId).classList.toggle(className)}

function hasClass(elem, className){return elem.classList.contains(className);}
function addClass(elem, className){return elem.classList.add(className);}
function removeClass(elem, className){return elem.classList.remove(className);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var svgData = byId("svgdiv").innerHTML;
    var url = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgData);
    getBase64FromImageUrl(url);
}

function getBase64FromImageUrl(URL) 
{
    var img = new Image();
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    // here code not working
    img.onload = function() 
    {
        console.log("FDF");
        var canvas = newEl("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
    };

    img.src = URL;
    console.log(img);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='svgdiv'>
        <svg id="svgRoot" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#009399"/>
        <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="50" fill="blue" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('fill', 'white')" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('fill', 'blue')"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```